# jQuery/CreateJS $.ajax "bitmap is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, createjs

I inherited a CreateJS and jQuery based product designer.

An $.ajax call is wrapped in an function named UrlLoader

```
function UrlLoader(params) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            beforeSend: function () {
                 console.log('sending');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                self.sucess(result);              
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
            }

        }).fail(function () {
            self.showError("Can't load remote data");
        });
}
```

The UrlLoader(params) function serves no other function that as a wrapper for the $.ajax call.

params is a JavaScript object:

When a design is created and saved, the system works as expected.
When a saved design is loaded from the same source it was saved to and then saved again the ajax call silently fails with no error.

Wrapping just the the $.ajax call in a try...catch block gives the error:

```
TypeError: bitmap is undefined
```

The objects for both the initial save and subsequent saves are nearly identical.  Both contain the same dataurl of an image object and other difference is one has an "id": 12474, element.  Both are properly formatted JavaScript objects.

The error seems to be a CreateJS error which does not make sense to me within a jQuery ajax call.

How can I identify the source of this error?

Comment: I found the problem.  The object is cloned from the CreateJS object using $.extend.  This apparently also clones some unknown CreateJS method.  Changing it to         var postData2 = $.extend(true, {}, self.params.params);
        var postData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(postData2)); seems to strip out the unneeded method calls.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The object is cloned from the CreateJS object using $.extend. This apparently also clones some unknown CreateJS method.

Changing:

```
var postData2 = $.extend(true, {}, self.params.params);
```

To:

```
var postData2 = $.extend(true, {}, self.params.params); 
var postData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(postData2));
```

seems to strip out the unneeded method calls.

Additional feedback on the underlying mechanism of why this worked would be awesome.

Comment: when equating objects in js - you are passing by reference. When you use JSON.parse with JSON.stringify, you are created a new memory pointer for that object and passing by value.